# When playing an MP3 from cache, Firefox displays "File not found"

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, audio-streaming, browser-cache

Calling [my script](http://www.bitesizeirishgaelic.com/process/play.php?sound_id=627) should play audio in your browser of type `audio/mpeg`.

The audio plays in Firefox when force-refreshing, but upon the second call the audio does not play.

The script tries to set `Cache-Control` to stop caching. Yet the browser seems to be caching, and is not able to retrieve the audio content.

On first call, my browser receives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2012 20:21:16 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-age=86400
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=627.mp3
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: 16299
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Feb 2012 21:58:33 GMT
Expires: Sat, 10 Mar 2012 20:21:16 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

On second call, though, it receives:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2012 20:21:54 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Expires: Sat, 10 Mar 2012 20:21:54 GMT
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-age=86400
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

... and the audio does not play.

Any hints on why this audio does not play upon the second call?